# Create product.product from dynamic product.template

Tags: odoo-13

I am wondering if there is an easy way to force the creation of a *specific* variant of a template. I know that you can add the variant you want to an SO and confirm it, but I was hoping to create a wizard or something to manually create the variant. The idea is to use a specific variant in a BoM for another product (dynamic variants cant be added to BoM until they are created).

We have a product that would end up creating over 800 variants if the attributes weren't set to dynamic. This wouldn't really be an issue except that not all combinations of variants are actually possible. We decided it would be cleaner to create the variants we need when we need them.

I tried the "product_variant_configurator" addon from OCA, but it fails some tests during build and then spits out an error when trying to actually create the variant.

Comment: It's out of the box at the moment for odoo base repo. For OCA module you could try opening an issue and then working in the fix.

Comment: @JuanSalcedo Sorry, what do you mean "out of the box"? Are you saying that odoo 13 has this functionality built-in? If so, how do I accomplish this?

Comment: I'm trying to say, that functionallity its not part of odoo rigth now. In order to work with variants you should assing the attribute and values to the template and let odoo calculate the total variants, it's how odoo works. I know it could be really anoing cause it could generate a tons of innecesary variants. I recomends you use "Create and Edit" options to create the product on the fly.